# C++ variadic template unusual example

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, variadic

What does the following construction mean?

```
#include <iostream>

template <int ...> struct s;

int main() {
    int i = s<,>::xxx;

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

It is compiled by gcc 4.4.5+ and when executed outputs `0`.

Comment: It outputs some random value on my machine. The initialization of `i` is somehow ignored and the unitialized value of `i` is printed.

Comment: It doesn't look legal. `s` is never defined (and does not contain an `xxx` member) and templates must be given non-empty parameters. (I compiled it with gcc 4.6.2, and it printed `32767`, clang won't compile it).

Comment: Changing the names of `s` or `xxx` does not change the behaviour. This is almost certainly a bug in gcc. It seems the bug is triggered by supplying empty arguments to a variadic template.

Comment: Interestingly, the problem still occurs even if `s` is defined and contains a member called `xxx`. Code just doesn't get generated for any expression containing `s<,>::xxx`.

Comment: It won't compile for me. I get the error: syntax error: missing ',' before '...'

'xxx': is not a member of ''global namespace''

Comment: @Mankarse: clang 3.0 complains with *error: expected expression* and points to the comma, do you have a more recent version with a better diagnosis ?

Comment: @Flyphe: Which compiler? If gcc, do you pass the `-std=c++0x`-switch?

Comment: mmmm im using visual studio 2010 however I tried it in cygwin and it complied fine. Interesting.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I'm using trunk, and the diagnostic is the same. It seems like a valid diagnosis though.

Comment: @Mankarse: definitely looks valid, I just wondered if it was more explicit :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. To me that sounds like the best possible diagnostic. It's pretty much what I thought when I looked at it: "hey, you need to put a thing there!" What else can one say about it?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: It's not bad per se, but I am used to more verbose diagnostics from clang :)

Comment: Reported as a gcc bug, http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53531

Comment: Even more interesting the situation with string: { string i = s<,>::xxx; std::cout << i << std::endl; } The object is allocated, but not constructed.

Answer (score 13):

I rewrote the program to this:

```
template <int ...> struct s;

int main() {
    int i = s<,>::xxx;

    return i;
}
```

and compiled it with the `-S`-switch, to get assembly output that I cleaned up to the following:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Now, my asm is a bit rusty, but the only significant code seems to be `movl -4(%rbp), %eax`, which sets the return value to whatever it can read from `i`. In other words, the program simply returns whatever was on top of the stack when the `main` function was entered. This seems to corroborate @jrok's comment that the initialization of `i` is somehow ignored. No code has been generated for the mystical `s<,>::xxx`-expression.

Bottom line; this looks like a compiler bug. The compiler should have given an error message.

Corroborating side note: I get identical assembly output for the program `int main() { int i; return i; }`.